# How to use javascript to preload images

Tags: javascript, preload

I have looked at a number of SO questions on how to preload images, I have created a function

```
$(images).each(function () {
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = this;
      $(img).appendTo('body').css('display', 'none');
 });
```

Which appends the images to the dom. However when I add a product to my cart, (the minicart will contain the images which have been preloaded), chrome still produces a request on that minicart image even though it has been preloaded (I can see the image in chrome developer tools). How do I get chrome to use the image which has already been loaded instead of getting another one from the server?

Comment: what happens if you dont append it to body?

Comment: You don't need to add it to the doc tree. Browsers download it before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- your server is sending wrong headers; do a search about `Cache-Control`, `Expires`, `Etag` and `Pragma` and set them to cache your images instead of download
- chrome is buggy or it intentionally downloads the image twice. for example setting `display:none` too early may cause the problem, use `position:absolute;left:-100000px;` instead
- your developer tools is set to disable cache (click on the gear icon, then uncheck `General > Disable cache (while DevTools is open)` )

Comment: Don't use left: -10000px.  Instead, just wrap the image in `<div style="display:none"><div><img /></div></div>`

Comment: even if it works on some browser, i wouldn't rely on display:none for this... better using position:absolute or visibility:collapse (which isn't xbrowser yet) imho!

Comment: I didn't know the trick, but I'm not saying that you are wrong, I'm saying that I wouldn't rely on a behavior that may change in future!

Comment: Thanks it was the headers